# I have a set of formula needed, but if blank how canI solve it? I tried some blank but not working

Tags: microsoft-excel

Example i have 3 set of data, and I want to know the min value for this 3 set.

```
1st set F4/E4
2nd set H4/G4
3rd set J4/I4
```

Let’s say 3rd set I do not have data(yellow highlight), I only want to compare 1st and 2nd set.

What should I input as formula? Below formula not working as it show 0 if any of the set is not filled.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfgxr.jpg)

Solved as below..
add price per unit as below formula

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(K8),ISBLANK(L8)),"",MIN(L8/K8))
```

then formula for min price along the data of price per unit

```
=IF(OR(F8,E8,I8,H8,L8,K8)<>"",MIN(G8,J8,M8))
```

[Solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4C4m.jpg)

Comment: Does F4,H4,J4 can be zero, and it is not treated as "no value"? Does any set value may be negative?

Comment: Did you mean if there is 0 value in cell, then don't return any values? If the all values in cells are not 0, then return the Min Value?

Comment: i mean there is 3 set of data, and if 1 set of data is zero i still want it to calculate the minimum.. example
1st set 100/2
2nd set 90/2
3rd set i put it blank.. the formula i input should calculate and put answer of 2nd set which is 45. (min value compared to 1st set which is 50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Following array (CSE) formula solves the issue:*

[image]

Formula in Cell `AN10`:

```
    {=MIN(IF($AN$2:$AN$8 <>"",$AN$2:$AN$8))}
```

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

---

**Edited 1:**

*Since OP is looking to get Unit wise Minimum value (through comments below) therefor I'm suggesting the following method.*

[image]

- Put Unit Name in `AM12:AM14`.
- You may use this array (CSE) formula in Cell `AM12`, to get the `UNIQUE Unit list`, if having long list for Units.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($AM$2:$AM$8, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($AM$11:AM11, $AM$2:$AM$8), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Array (CSE) Formula in Cell `AN12`.

`{=MIN(IF(AM$2:AM$8=AM12,IF(AN$2:AN$8<>"",AN$2:AN$8)))}`

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

---

**Edited 2:**

*The prime reason behind 2nd edit is, final twist given by the OP (uploaded screen shot).*

[image]

- Array (CSE) formula in Cell `M32`.

  `{=IF(F32:K32>0,MIN(F32*G32,H32*I32,J32*K32),0)}`

**C**opy formula in Cell `M34` also.

**N.B.**

- Reason behind Multiply data instead of Division is, avoid `#DIV/0`error, since `J34 & K34` are blank.
- Also, logically `Quantity multiplied by Price`.
- Additionally, this array formula may be used also in Cell `N32 & N34`.

`{=MIN(IF($F32:$K$34 >0,$F$32:$K$32))}`

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: how post picture? mine a little complicated like what you post.. lets say you using column AM and AN. . AM as unit, AN as price.. so i want to calculate min price per unit which is AN/AM and i want the lowest value which is minimum.. so i able to draft this formula if all value is filled, if i dont fill one of the row i will get DIV or NA.. i want a formula which ignore to calculate if its blank..

Comment: @user1093648,, for post the sample data (picture),, select the data Range like `AM1:AN9`,, copy it & either paste in Editor Window,, or better press `Print Screen Button` ,  Open `Paint Brush` then Paste there,, next select the required rectangle portion,, Paste in New Paint brush file Save it and upload in Editor along with OP. Soon I'll edit my post & show you how to get Minimum for each category.

Comment: i thought there is option to upload in comment, so actually only in main post to update. i already input the picture.. but it wont show and we need to click.. i not sure.. after click the picture you shall have a better image ..

Comment: @user1093648,, check the Edited part of my post above,, I've now shown how to get MIN on Units!!

Comment: Hi Rajesh, i partially understand some and did some modification.. but i think you had misunderstand my meaning.. Using your picture, how about filling AM column as below value 
AM2 = 3 AN2 = 1
AM3 = 6 AN3 = 2
AM4 = 8 AN4 = 8
Then i need to find the min value for AM/AN across the 3 row. It should be showing value of 1 (because lowest is AM4/AN4 which is 8/8 = 1)
But my condition is, if one of the range in AM2:AN4 is not filled, i will get DIV

Comment: @user1093648,, since  you have given so many twist to the question,, everything is been messed up,, the 2 edited part is addressing to the sample data you have added,, hope this works,  also read N.B. carefully.

Comment: sorry for the unclear info.. actually from the beginning to the end i want the same thing.. i figure it out for a solution and work out.. so actually must be multiply instead of divide.. 
i use divide because i want to know cost per unit (150pcs = 3000usd example) instead of total cost.. thanks anyway..appreciate it

Comment: Glad to help you @user1093648,, keep asking ☺